# Error on IONIC 3 validation form

Tags: ionic3, angular5, angular2-formbuilder

i have a 2 problems: 
1: validation required only show if i click 2 times in field, in first time show a valid, and in second time show a invalid field with ng-invalid class(correct but it was show in first blur of field event).
2: i'm using one method to set a value in field but validation still ng-invalid.

home.ts

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
addressForm: FormGroup;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
            public navParams: NavParams,
            public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.addressForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        address:    [ '', [ Validators.required ]]
    });

}  

getGeolocation(form) {
    console.log(form.value);
    this.addressForm.setValue({'address':'Some word'})
}

saveGeoLocation(form) {
    console.log(form.value)
}
}
```

home.html

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="addressForm" >
    <ion-list no-border padding no-margin>
        <ion-item no-padding>
            <ion-label stacked>{{ 'ADDRESS' | translate }}</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="address" name="address" placeholder="{{ 'ADDRESS_EXAMPLE' | translate }}" text-wrap></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <br />
        <button type="button" ion-button color="color-green" block clear (click)="getGeolocation(addressForm)" >
            <ion-icon name="navigate" icon-start></ion-icon>
             {{ 'MY_LOCATION' | translate }}
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</form>
```

screenshot
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCcNX.png)

thanks for any help :)

@edit
i forgot show my workplace
[here my environment setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izCRx.png)